# Is there a kernel parameter to hide/disable disk at boot time?

Tags: kernel, disk, devices

I am looking to install a new linux distro in my computer and I'd like for it to not have access to other disks in my pc (e.g the disk where I have all my documents, other operating systems, etc.)

Ideally I'd like that not even the root user could mount those partitions, through some searching online I think this could be done via kernel parameters, but I haven't found one that suits this case.

I know I could also do it via udev but I'd really prefer something stronger (at boot time).

Why do I need all of this? I might do some penetration testing/exploit development in the pc and thus run untrusted code. Doing all of this in a vm is not an option due to multiple reasons.

Comment: May I ask why don't you want to use a VM? It provides isolation and can be configured even for network isolation.

Alternatively, consider using a container.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel has no such options, and malware potentially running under the root user will be able to circumvent most if not all limitations regardless.

You do not run untrusted code on your hardware unless you've got nothing to lose and you're OK with wiping it all clean.

Answer (score 0):

The only safe solution preventing availability to the hardware.

I recommend unplugging the power cables to the disks you don't want that OS to have access to. Since you have to reboot to use them anyway, this is not a big loss.